# AWS Boto3: Access denied while running in Django Server

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, boto3

My textract code is successfully working when running in its own file, however, when I try to run it in my django development server, the authentication stops working.

I recieve this exception:

```
botocore.errorfactory.InvalidS3ObjectException: An error occurred (InvalidS3ObjectException) when calling the StartDocumentAnalysis operation: Unable to get object metadata from S3. Check object key, region and/or access permissions.
```

So far, I have tried:

1. Passing credentials as parameters in the boto.client() method
2. Assuming a role, rather than using IAM user credentials
3. Verified the object key, and region
4. Checked my firewall

Here is my authentication format:

```
client = boto3.client('sts', region_name="us-east-2") # Assumes a role.
response = client.assume_role(
    RoleArn='arn:aws:iam::xxx:role/xxx/xxx',
    RoleSessionName = 'djangoBoto3',
    DurationSeconds = 3600,
)
textract = boto3.client( # Instantiate the textract client
    "textract", 
    region_name="us-east-2",
    aws_access_key_id = response['Credentials']['AccessKeyId'],
    aws_secret_access_key = response['Credentials']['SecretAccessKey'],
    aws_session_token = response['Credentials']['SessionToken']
)
```

Here is how I am calling the textract function

```
response = textract.start_document_analysis(
    DocumentLocation = {
        'S3Object':{
            'Bucket': bucket,
            'Name': key,
        }
    },
    FeatureTypes = ['TABLES', 'FORMS']
)
```

Some AWS API calls are working within Django. For example I can upload files to S3 buckets. This leads me to suspect maybe this could be a signature issue. I read here [Amazon Docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/signing_aws_api_requests.html) that certain AWS operations such as S3 can work without a signature.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the same region for the Textract and S3 bucket, and if using a Role make sure that it has proper permissions to access both S3 and Textract.